# SuperSort `rsortAs` error with `postDate`

Tags: postdate, plugin-supersort

In Craft CMS Twig template I am trying to sort Entries by post date using SuperSort.

An old template on Craft CMS 3.0.17.1 PRO is using:

```
{% set products = products | supersort('rsortAs', '{ postDate }') %}
```

And this works as expected.

But after updating to Craft CMS 3.4.17.1 PRO this is throwing an error:

```
PHP Recoverable Error – yii\base\ErrorException
Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string
```

I tried updating to:

```
{% set products = products | supersort('rsortAs', '{ entry.postDate }') %}
```

But the sorting does not work as expected, ie. nothing is sorted by date.

I saw this [Using Supersort with date field](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/12244/using-supersort-with-date-field) but that is not helpful as I am using the latest plugin version.

I'm missing something or doing something wrong?!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, needed to format the `postDate` object accordingly:

```
{% set products = products | supersort('rsortAs', '{ postDate | date("U") }') %}
```